# Should non SE links and references be replaced with SE Q&A

Tags: discussion

Generally speaking, should off-site links be edited and replaced with ones on the Stack Overflow network?

I've seen links to blogs, etc that discuss encryption that may be better served with a link to  a specific Security.SE or Cryptology.SE question.

- In the situation that a SE answer and a blog offers equally unbiased valid technical advice, which one should be linked to?
- When should SE links be given preferential treatment? *(links affect SEO, no?)*
- Should older questions be edited to point to an SE answer if it offers more up-to-date valid information?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can't see how this makes sense. A blog article or external reference isn't something you can simply replace with content from the SE network, is it? Also, a Stack Exchange contribution isn't inherently better than a blog article.

If you have a SE resource that helps answer a question, either post a new answer, or close as duplicate.

Comment: The main thought being that the answer is on another site.  AFAIK - different sites don't count as duplicates.  I just want to make sure that I don't mess up SE's SEO when I link to different resources

Comment: @makerofthings7: If the answer is on a different SE site, should the question not be migrated to that site and closed as a duplicate?  There's certainly overlap between SE sites, but effort should be made to define the boundaries.  If a question has been answered on another site, there's a very good chance the question itself _belongs_ on that other site.

Answer (score 0):

> Generally speaking, should off-site links be edited and replaced with ones on the Stack Overflow network?

For what purpose?  In an ideal world, the content on the Stack Exchange site (be it a question or an answer) should be whole and complete.  Links to external resources can be used as reference, but should not be used as content.  If an SE post says something like, "click here to see an example of what I'm talking about" then it should be edited to include that example, not edited to link elsewhere.

> - In the situation that a SE answer and a blog offers equally unbiased valid technical advice, which one should be linked to?

That's up to the person who posted the content, I suppose.  You're certainly free to edit any questions/answers as you see fit.  Perhaps adding the link to the SE site to provide further context for the question/answer would be a good idea.  But mass-replacing people's links with other links is probably a bad idea.  You run the risk of changing the meaning of the content for little purpose other than to try to internalize all knowledge to Stack Exchange.

> - When should SE links be given preferential treatment?

I'm not sure what you mean by this.  Preferential treatment for what?  A link is a link is a link.

> - Should older questions be edited to point to an SE answer if it offers more up-to-date valid information?

From what you're saying here, it sounds to me like one of these questions is a duplicate of another.  If someone asks a question on a Stack Exchange site and the answer to that question consists of a link to another answer, the question itself should probably be closed as a duplicate.